# Is there a way in C++ to determine if a string is "interned" or in a read only persistent location?

Tags: c++

many compilers and loaders will assign strings simply declared as "a string" to read only persistent memory segments. Is there a way to determine this at runtime so as not to allocate duplicates when persistence is desired and one gets passed "const char *" arguments ?  Also to prevent freeing them.

Comment: You should know what was allocated explicitely with your code, and that you have to deallocate it, Any other situations don't need to use `free()` or `delete`.

Comment: Exactly. If you have to interpret your own code at runtime you have much bigger problems than this.

Comment: You probably want to use `std::string_view` or other functions for [dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: Note - I have used this facility in non-standard programs where there are OS or loader specific utilities to determine these things.  It is useful when implementing things like string interning for symbol keys or on systems with limited memory.  My question is pretty much if any of this has migrated into the official standards.

Comment: @peterk Just write ***clean code*** that redeems you from bothering with such silly stuff.

Comment: I think having a library that can protect itself from caller abuse AND be optimized is clean code.  There would be no efficient standard templates if no one thought about "this silly stuff"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic answer is no. Not in a portable way.

So there isn't really a way to tell the difference when a (bad interface) function returns memory that is static or dynamically allocated. E.g.,

```
char* num_to_string(int number) {
    static char buffer[5];
    if(number < 10000) {
        std::sprintf(buffer, "%d", number);
        return buffer;
    }
    char* bigger_buffer = new char[50];
    std::sprintf(bigger_buffer, "%d", number);
    return bigger_buffer;
}
```

The use of the above function will be unable to (without looking at the implementatin) when he is repsonsible for cleaning up the memory returned.

Comment: The use case specifically for me is whether I need to do a strdup or use std::string as keys in a symbol table or just put the string in the map.  

as in symbol = table.add("symbolName");

Comment: @peterk From your description, I'd go for `std::string` since it handles its own memory. With `strdup` you are always responsible for the returned memory.

Comment: yes but useful in a case like an embedded system symbol table not to have to duplicate the memory usage, hence the question :)

Comment: Well if using C++17 there's this hand alternative called `std::string_view` that can reuse memory.

Comment: Thanks - I did look at that :)